# CakePHP: How to contain all top level associations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to set $options['contain'] such that ALL top level associated models are included (but not the second degree associations). I know I can simply list every single model...

```
$this->Object->find('all', array('contain'=>array('Model1', 'Model2', ...
```

But that's NOT what I want because additional models might be associated in the future, and I'd like them to included automatically.

I think I remember older versions of CakePHP allowing something like...

```
$this->Object->find('all', array('contain'=>array('*')
```

But so far (on v2.4) it doesn't seem to work.

After re-reading [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), it sounds like what I want *should* happen by default. But it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Model attribute `recursive`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Setting it to level `0` will pull one level of associations.

Containable is for when you want to specify which models and is almost always recommended over using recursive, BUT - in your case pulling "all" top-level associated models would be done w/ recursive without the need for Containable at all.

Recursive is, by default set to `1`, however I have heard in future versions of Cake, recursive will be going away (good riddance).  Most people set `public $recursive = -1;` in their AppModel to default it to "off".

Comment: Thanks Dave. Is 'recursive' allowed as a key in the $options array for find? Do you know if it will trump `'contain'` if it's set somewhere else upstream?

Comment: Per the [documentation on find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find), you can set recursive on a per-find basis.  When using Containable Behavior, though, you should be setting recursive to -1.

Comment: I gave it a shot and it works! However, HABTM relationships are including their "join association" as well, even though 'recursive' is set to 1. Is that expected?

Comment: I think you actually probably want '0', not '1'.  Details here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive  (recommendation would be to not use recursive at all though - it's bad practice IMO - stick with Containable instead.  I know you're not going to, but I have to say that :)

Comment: To be more concrete... If I'm searching for User objects and User HABTM Tags, I'm seeing a TagsUser key inside of the Tag array for the returned data. It's probably fine because it doesn't list any other TagsUser(s) for that Tag. Just the relationship for that object.

Comment: I never use recursive (always contain). But in this one particular instance I think it's the right tool for the job because we want to make a single DB request for the current user and then access it via $this->Auth->user() thereafter. Do you approve of this application?

Comment: The fact (or rumor at least) that the plan is to remove recursive all-together makes me think it's still not a good reason to use it.  Would Containable not work for that same purpose?  It's not the end of the world. Plenty of people still use recursive.  I've personally just had a number of headaches with it. But - setting it to level 0 is making the best of a bad solution at least :)  In my opinion, if you want more data, specifying what data you want is better than allowing it to decide for you - which is the general argument for Containable vs recursive.

Comment: I think we just agreed that containble is specifically designed to pick and choose individual models to be included. And this is exactly what I don't want to do (in this particular situation). Because I will always want every associated model, and if I'm using contain I will have to come back and update it every time I add a new relationship. If there was `'contain'=>'all'` or something it would be perfect.